# Retrieving data from SQL using C# Metro App

Tags: c#, sql, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am new to programming Metro App for Win8 using C#. I am familiar with C# already, but when I try to use the C# code for connecting and retrieving info from a SQL Database, it does not work.

Main problem is I cannot reference the "using System.Data / .SqlClient", thus I can't use the SqlConnection / DataReader. I could not find a workaround to this.

Edit: Upon further research, I found out that Windows 8 Apps does not support access to local services(hence cannot access Local SQL) based on this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/c1c6aa70-5be9-496c-9d2d-a5b0fc0890a9

Does anyone with experience can help me point in the right direction for SQL / Windows 8 App integration?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to add a reference to the project or just tried using?

Comment: C# for Metro Apps(now called `Windows 8 UI`) is the same C# you used with, for example, WinForms application.

Comment: I also tried to add a reference ... still no luck ... upon further research, I found out that Windows 8 Apps does not support access to local services(hence cannot access Local SQL) based on this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/c1c6aa70-5be9-496c-9d2d-a5b0fc0890a9

Comment: You'll have to write your own API (as in a web service) to access data from SQL.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work using WCF service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, System.Data is unavailable to Metro apps.  If you need to store / retrieve data then you either need to do it to a file (isolated storage) or via a service.

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, as uncia pointed out below using a standalone SQLite db file in local storage is a viable option for local structured storage. Unfortunately the SQL Server team has not YET announced any roadmap regarding SQL CE and WinRT. The updated instructions for using SQLite can be found here: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should use sqllite for WinRT as described here

http://timheuer.com/blog/

Answer (score -1):

You should implement application server which will expose all necessary methods to access data . And in this case Metro app will use these service methods to get data from DB.