# Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Data.dll'

Tags: c#, mongodb, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I just created a new windows 8 app in c#/XML and download  [mongodb c# driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/) and add its reference in my project and follows the rest of [tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/) , but when i try to run my app now its saying

```
Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Data.dll'

Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
```

Please help me thanks in advance .

Comment: What version(s) of the .NET framework do you have installed?

Comment: @DavinTryon  i have installed 4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `system.data` is unavailable to metro apps. The general consensus seems to be that you'll have to create a middle "go-between" tier (using a technology such as WCF) to allow your metro app to communication with the database.

References:

- [Retrieving data from SQL using C# Metro App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947078/retrieving-data-from-sql-using-c-sharp-metro-app)
- [Make System.Data available to Metro style apps](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2759791-make-system-data-available-to-metro-style-apps)
- [WinRT System.Data - Connect to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193999/winrt-system-data-connect-to-sql)

Although these links have SQL in the title, they really address connecting metro apps directly to any database.

Here's a bit from an answer at one of the above links:

> You are correct, System.Data is not there (I looked for the same thing when I first started messing around with WinRT). You won't be able to reference it either. If you want to talk to a SQL database you're going to need to use some kind of other protocol (WebService, SOAP, WCF, etc.).

---

Followup question in comment:

> I am trying to connect with mongodb , not sql . Is it necessary to have system.data for this purpose ?

When I tried this, I could reference `MongoDB.Bson.dll` by itself and the project builds, but once I referenced `MongoDB.Driver.dll` I got the same message as you.

It would appear the sql driver and the mongodb driver both require `System.Data.dll`, which you could reference directly in a standard winforms/wpf app (but probably shouldn't), but which you cannot reference directly in a metro app.

I'd say it's necessary to have access to `System.Data` if you want to use MongoDB. So you'll have to create a separate project that references the MongoDB driver and actually performs the connections to the database, and make that project accessible to your metro app via WCF calls or a web service. You just need something sitting between your metro app and the database, because you cannot connect directly to it.

I know it seems to make things more complicated, especially if you're just trying to play around, but it's apparently a design decision Microsoft made regarding their metro apps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these posts, it mentions that the DLL is not yet available: [Using NHibernate in a Metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926502/using-nhibernate-in-a-metro) &
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/DataMarket/thread/385475ce-edf9-416f-b0f7-1369760aa73b/

Comment: these are some of the first result when i ask this from google , but these link doesn't help